# UIRefreshControl at Bottom of UICollectionView (load more data)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` which displays images from an online database. I first load 10 images, and then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the `UICollectionView` I load another 10 images in the background and refresh the view. I accomplish this using the following method :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (self.localFeedContent != nil && self.localFeedContent!.count > 0) {
         if indexPath.item == (self.localFeedContent!.count-1) {
        loadMoreData()
    }
    }

}
```

Now this works perfectly fine, however there is no indication to the user that the process is complete and unless he scrolls further down, he won't notice that new content has been added. I would like to implement a `UIRefreshControl` which will be attached to the bottom of the `UICollectionView` and mimic the same exact behaviour as the regular `UIRefreshControl` on top of the screen does. I have already implemented one on top of the screen, however I am not sure how to do this at the bottom as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've written something similar - I return another cell at the bottom that just shows a `UIActivityIndicator`.  So your datasource would be something similar to:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count + 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == array.count{
        // return the new UICollectionViewCell with an activity indicator
    }
    // return your regular UICollectionViewCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == array.count{
        // loadMoreData()
    }
}
```

Or instead of calling `loadMoreData()` in `willDisplayCell`, you could call it in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method (when you're returning the new `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UIActivityIndicator`).  Either could work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using indexPath.row in a collectionView, probably you meant indexPath.item?

Comment: @xaphod both work, but I'll edit my answer to use `.item` as it's probably more relevant to UICollectionView :)

Comment: how do you then hide that new cell once there are no more pages to load?

Comment: @Halpo If you are keeping track of a Boolean on whether you can load more pages or not, say `canLoadNextPage`, then in `numberOfItems` method you return `canLoadNextPage ? array.count + 1 : array.count`.  Hope that helps!

Comment: the Delegate func is no longer valid, please keep updated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a `UIRefreshControl` on the bottom, just implement a `scrollView` method to do some action when the scroll reach the bottom of screen. You can use some flags inside the conditional to more get a more specific action.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let threshold = 100.0 as CGFloat!
        let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
        if (maximumOffset - contentOffset <= threshold) && (maximumOffset - contentOffset != -5.0) {            //Add ten more rows and reload the table content.

            runMoreAPI()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The point is to have an indicator that the API is loading data.

Comment: I can't see Refresh control at the bottom implementing this method@kileros

Comment: This method execute the `runMoreApi()` when the scroll reach the bottom of the screen. The idea is: when reach the bottom, refresh