# How to add Activity indicator to end of UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

Hi I have been trying to add an Activity Indicator, or a Loading spinner, to the bottom of my collection view. I have searched online on how to do so but there is not a clear way to do so.

I do not want to use a cell for the indicator itself because my cells a pretty big. (2 cells take up the whole screen.) So I would just like to have a small loading spinner at the bottom for when users scroll down.

Through the research that I have done I have seen that some people use this function below and a separate class to build the spinner.

```
private func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{}
```

But I do not know how to use it. I already created a class called `LoadingViewController()` but in all honesty don't know if it is event he right type. Currenlty I have it set as a `UICollectionReusableView`

For a little more background, I already added the ability paginate data. So when I scroll down the collection view, new cells are loaded. Now the problem is I want to show a little spinner at the bottom when the data is loading because if not the app stutters and looks like it is broken.

Or is there a better way to show load items in a collection view that does not cause the scroll to freeze?

Please let me know if you have any questions regarding my situation I'll try to answer them to the best of my ability.

Comment: you can create another collectionView cell for loader/UIactivity indicator. Follow this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815893/2092593

Comment: Is there a better way to do that does not create another cell? @ShujaUdDin